# How do I add a list of figures/tables for Latex/PDF output?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I trying to add a list of figures and a list of tables into a PDF document generated by Sphinx+Latex. So far I found nothing useful..

Would somebody know how to do it? Thanks

Comment: You should at least provide what you've done thus far, either in terms of your Sphinx code, or the LaTeX code produced by Sphinx. Otherwise it's difficult to assess where the problem may lie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To whom it may interest, I found out that Sphinx can pass native commands to Latex.

Thus the following Sphinx source code snippet does what I was looking for:

```
..raw:: latex

  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering with the sphinx document class **manual**, adding raw LaTeX commands

```
..raw:: latex

  \listofequations
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
  \listof{literalblock}{List of Code Blocks}
```

puts the lists onto pages with arabic numerals instead of pages with roman numerals.

Here is a LaTeX snippet, which goes into the LaTeX preamble setup in **conf.py**. It redefines the  command sequence `\sphinxtableofcontents`:

```py
latex_elements['preamble'] = r'''
%% --------------------------------------------------
%% |:sec:| add list of figures, list of tables, list of code blocks to TOC
%% --------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sphinxtableofcontents}{%
  %
  % before resetting page counter, let's do the right thing.
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \pagenumbering{roman}%
  \begingroup
    \parskip \z@skip
    \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
  %
  %% addtional lists
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}%
  \listoffigures
  %
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}%
  \listoftables
  %
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Code Blocks}%
  \listof{literalblock}{List of Code Blocks}%
  %
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
\makeatother
'''
```

If there should not be any entries in the table of contents for the lists, remove the `\addcontentsline` commands.